# How to substitute the middle of an XML element by a predefined string using regular expressions?

Tags: java, xml, regex

I need to transfer an XML string converting the password element to the string containing the 1st and the last character and the rest should be filled by x. The length of the element string should remain the same. For example,

```
<UserPassword>Douve</UserPassword>
```

should be converted to

```
<UserPassword>Dxxxe</UserPassword>.
```

I program in Java but would like to avoid XML parsing, just use regular expression.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but why do you want to "avoid XML parsing"?

Comment: Thank you. I think that regex is faster than parsing. Second, theoretically, XML can be of different structures

Comment: It's probably true, but keep in mind that it is not always the safer way (example: the UserPassword tag can have an attribute). However, XPath can easily deals with variable XML trees.

Comment: Use the tool specifically designed for these kinds of problems (XSLT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?:(?<=<UserPassword>.)|\\G(?<!^)).(?=[^<]+</UserPassword>)
```

and this replacement:

```
x
```

with the `replaceAll` method.

Example:

```
String pattern = "(?:(?<=<UserPassword>.)|\\G(?<!^)).(?=[^<]+</UserPassword>)";
yourstr = yourstr.replaceAll(pattern, "x");
```

Pattern details:

```
(?:                       # open a non capturing group
    (?<=<UserPassword>.)  # lookbehind: preceded by <UserPassword> and a character
  |                       # OR
    \\G(?<!^)             # contiguous to a precedent match but not at the start of the string
)                         # close the non capturing group
.                         # a character
(?=                       # lookahead: followed by 
    [^<]+                 #  at least one character (that is not a <)
    </UserPassword>       #  and </UserPassword>
)                         # close the lookahead assertion
```

Notes:

If the *UserPassword* tag can have attributes, you can change `<UserPassword>` to `<UserPassword\b[^>]{0,1000}>` in the pattern. In Java limited variable length lookbehinds are allowed.

I assume here that the password doesn't contains newlines or `<`.

Comment: Thank you, looks working.  How to substitute for all xxx without keeping the first and last character?

Comment: @anarinsky: remove the `.` in the lookbehind and replace `[^<]+` by `[^<]*` in the lookahead.

Comment: outstanding, use of precedent match! +1

Answer (score 1):

Try regex `(?<=<UserPassword>.)\w*?(?=.</UserPassword>)` to find the password. The lookbehind and lookahead do not count. Then use the size of the match and replace the match with the number of `x` of the size of the match. See [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for doc.

You can not use `replaceAll` because the number of needed x's is unknown until the match hits. If it is always 3 x's then you can just use the whole pattern on the left in replaceAll and replace with `xxx`.

Comment: Thank you, how to write this expression in a Java code using the string method replaceAll

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<UserPassword>\\w)(\\w*)(\\w</UserPassword>)");
String input = "<UserPassword>Douve</UserPassword> ";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.replaceFirst("$1xxx$3"));
}
```

The key is [`Matcher.replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String%29). In the output the first and third group are retained while the second is replaced by 'xxx'.

Comment: Thank you. In your response the substitution always has 3 x.  How to change it, so the number of characters is the same in the substitution and original?